# Torques In Gears

Tags: classical-mechanics, torque

I had a question regarding the gear ratio of spur gears. Assuming that the gears mesh properly (roll without slipping), I was taught that the ratio of the torques acting on the gears is equal to the ratio of the radii. I was wondering how this was derived and came up with the following.

Say gear 1was driven with a torque $\tau_1$ which exerted a torque of $\tau_2$ on gear 2. Since the gears roll without slipping, the linear acceleration of the point of contact is $a$ for both gears. From this, $a=a\implies \alpha_1 R_1 = \alpha_2 R_2 \implies \frac{T_1 R_1}{I_1}=\frac{T_2 R_2}{I_2}\implies T_2=\frac{I_2 R_1}{R_2 I_1} T_1$ where the subscript 1 represents quantities of gear 1 and the subscript of 2 represents quantities of gear 2. Assuming that the moment of inertia of the gears can be modelled by a cylinder, this equation becomes $T_{2}=\frac{M_{2}R_{2}^{2}R_{1}}{R_{2}M_{1}R_{1}^{2}}T_{1}=\frac{M_{2}R_{2}}{M_{1}R_{1}}T_{1}$.

Now it seems that the ratio of the torques depends on both the radii of the gears and their respective masses. Did I do something wrong with this derivation? If it is correct, could gears of varying density be used to change the torque ratio?

Comment: In constant rotational velocity the density would not matter. Under acceleration the density would affect the "flywheel" effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OP's torque relation is true if we are interested in the torques during the acceleration of a set of gears without a load, until reaching some desired speed. And if both gears are independently driven, in a way that there is no force $F$ between teeth, so that for each one $\tau = I\alpha$.

On the other hand, if for example, gear 1 is driven by a motor and gear 2 only moves due gear 1, it is true that for gear 2: $\tau_2 = FR_2 = I_2\alpha_2$.

But the reaction force of the same magnitude $F$ acts on gear 1 in the opposite direction of its acceleration! So, the equation here is: $\tau_1 - FR_1 = I_1\alpha_1$, where $\tau_1$ is the torque delivered by the motor.

Equating the value of $F$ in both equations:
$$\frac{\tau_1 - I_1\alpha_1}{R_1} = \frac{\tau_2}{R_2}$$
We can think of the numerator of the LHS as the available torque to drive gear 2, after using some amount to accelerate gear 1.

When $\alpha_1$ (and by consequence $\alpha_2$) is zero, when have the usual relation between torque and radius. It is the case of a shaft driven by a motor linked by the gear to another shaft, that does some work with a constant angular speed. In this case, the power is: $P = \tau_1\omega_1 = \tau_2\omega_2$. The linear speed at the contact point is the same: $\omega_1 R_1 = \omega_2 R_2$ and $$\frac{\tau_1}{\tau_2} = \frac{R_1}{R_2}$$

Comment: Ah thank you, does the power being the same across both gears just come from conservation of energy?

Comment: Yes, and that requires negligible loss by friction on the bearings. Otherwise the torque delivered to gear 2 by gear 1: $FR_1$, where F is the contact force between gears, is only part of the torque from the motor.

Comment: I edited the answer to better analise the accelerated case.